# DOI does not appear in bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle, doi

I am having this problem with elsarticle. When I compile the file the doi does not appear in the bibliography entries.

```
\documentclass[review, authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{lineno, hyperref, chngcntr, array, booktabs, enumitem, multirow, tabu, subcaption, nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, cleveref, thmtools, thm-restate, lmodern, natbib}
\usepackage{wrapfig, graphicx, framed, ragged2e, mathtools, epsfig, adjustbox, parskip, doi}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Be05,
author  = "Fernando Bernstein and Awi Federgruen",
title   = "Decentralized Supply Chains with Competing Retailers Under Demand Uncertainty",
journal = "Management Science",
volume  = "51",
number  = "1",
pages   = "18--29",
year    =  "2005",
doi     = "10.1287/mnsc.1040.0218"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}\title{Some Title}\end{frontmatter}
\cite{Be05}
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

I compile it with TexWorks using the option pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex or the option PdfLaTeX/ then bibtex/ then 2 times PdfLaTeX. Everything else works as it should. The problem appears when I use the option

```
authoryear
```

If I ommit it it works fine, but then the citations are numbered (as they should) which is not what I want.

Can anyone please explain to me what is wrong with my code and fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Not solving your problem, but because you use DOIs I wanted to point out that there is http://shortdoi.org/ - can be helpful for dois which span several lines, include cryptic characters, and show all sorts of additional problems (and typewriting by the reader (if printed and not electronically/copy&paste) to get there is also a nightmare).