# DOI does not appear in bibliography entries in authoryear mode

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle, doi

I am having this problem with elsarticle. When I compile the file the doi does not appear in the bibliography entries.

```
\documentclass[review, authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref, doi}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Be05,
author  = "Fernando Bernstein and Awi Federgruen",
title   = "Decentralized Supply Chains with Competing Retailers Under Demand Uncertainty",
journal = "Management Science",
volume  = "51",
number  = "1",
pages   = "18--29",
year    =  "2005",
doi     = "10.1287/mnsc.1040.0218"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Be05}
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

I compile it with TexWorks using the option pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex or the option PdfLaTeX/ then bibtex/ then 2 times PdfLaTeX. Everything else works as it should. The problem appears when I use the option

```
authoryear
```

If I ommit it it works fine, but then the citations are numbered (as they should) which is not what I want.

Can anyone please explain to me what is wrong with my code and fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Hallo, this is a repost. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/doi-does-not-appear-in-bibliography-entries I posted the same question some time ago as a guest. I would like to delete the previous one and keep this one. Sorry for the trouble...

Comment: @jknappen. Ok, I posted my first post as a guest, so I cannot modify it.

Comment: Do you really get a DOI if you don't use the `authoryear` option? I don't get a DOI then either. And as far as I can see, the CTAN version of `elsarticle-harv.bst` simply does not support DOIs. The styles `elsarticle-num-names.bst` and `elsarticle-num.bst` have DOI support added via [`urlbst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urlbst), you could try and do the same for `elsarticle-harv.bst`.

Comment: @moewe Ok thanks! If I replace elsarticle-harv with elsarticle-num-names then I get following warning:Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...doi.org/\let \@tempa \bibinfo@X@doi 
                                                  10.1287/mnsc.1040.0218
l.16 ...doi{\bibinfo{doi}{10.1287/mnsc.1040.0218}}

Comment: @moewe. You are right, If I remove authoryear I do not get a doi neither. I used to remove all the time both author year and harv style. Thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: I just checked if `urlbst` works. Unfortunately, I could not get it to work immediately, because `elsarticle-harv.bst` already has a `url` field, and so `urlbst` refuses to change the file, even though we don't have a `doi` field.

Comment: @moewe Perhaps if you change the "url" to "doi" with DeclarFormat or with renewcommand or something like that?

Comment: The commands you mention sound very `biblatex`-y, they can't help us here. I could probably modify the style manually, but I'm not sure if I could do that in a way to not break anything if `urlbst` is run afterwards (I'm thinking of double URLs). Anyway, if you write an article for Elsevier it is probably not a good idea to mess with their templates, they are templates for a reason. And if you don't write for Elsevier, then why do you have to us their class?

Comment: @moewe. Yes, I do not like to change their template. No, I need to use their template. Thanks a lot for your comments!! At least I know now that harv does not support doi's and that is why it does not work! Thanks again!!!